# Error Cannot Instantiate Abstract Class when Instantiating Inherited Class

Tags: c++, game-loop

This is my generic C++ game loop:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<State>> states;

while(window.isOpen())
{
    //event checking and other stuff

    for(size_t i = 0; i < states.size(); i++)
    {
        states[i]->Update();

        //clear backbuffer
        states[i]->Draw(window);
        //draw backbuffer
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I remove a state from the `states` list the program crashes. I'm guessing it's because once the state has been removed you can no longer use the object because its obviously not there any more.

I'm pretty sure the best way to fix this is to copy the states inside the `states` vector into a new one and just make any changes that I want to the `states` vector that way no changes will be made during the loop.

So this is what I came up with:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<State>> states;
std::vector<State> tempStates;

while(window.isOpen())
{
    //event checking and other stuff

    for(size_t i = 0; i < states.size(); i++)
    {
        tempStates.push_back(*states[i]);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < tempStates.size(); i++)
    {
        tempStates[i].Update();

        //clear backbuffer
        tempStates[i].Draw(window);
        //draw backbuffer
    }

    tempStates.clear();
}
```

But I get an error once building the application saying `error C2259: 'State' : cannot instantiate abstract class` in file `xmemory0`. "State" is my abstract base class that other states inherit from. I don't understand why I'm getting this error because I'm not instantiating that abstract class, I'm instantiating a class that inherits from it. `states` isn't full of `State` objects it's full of objects that inherit from it which I guess would make it full of `State` objects in a way, but regardless I'm not instantiating them.

So why do I get this error and how can I solve it?

Thanks.

*EDIT*

This is basically how an element inside `states` gets removed when using the first method described above. This is inside a class that inherits from `State`:

```
void Update()
{
    if(/*whatever*/)
    {
        StateManager::RemoveState(std::unique_ptr<State>(this));
        //call stack comes back here but cant because this no longer exists
    }
}
```

StateManager.cpp

```
void StateManager::RemoveState(std::unique_ptr<State> state)
{
    states.erase(std::remove(states.begin(), states.end(), state), states.end());
}
```

Comment: Show a typical code example of how states get removed.

Comment: So your basic problem is that StateManager is unaware of the active iteration of the very thing it is "managing", problem contributed to by states being able to essentially shoot their own head off and extricate themselves from the StateManager's collection mid-iteration? It almost seems like you should let each state *mark* itself for death, then have the StateManager sweep up the bodies at the end of each loop iteration. Would that solve your problem ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Precisely! Yes, that is the problem. I've implemented this brilliant solution and it works as expected.

Comment: @ProgrammerGuy123 nothing brilliant about it. But glad it worked for you. I *hope* it does, anyway ("as expected' might not be a good thing when you 'expect' it to fail =P).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would be simple to *transfer* the elements you want to delete:

```
std::vector<unique_ptr<state>> states;

while ( /* stuff */)
{
    std::vector<unique_ptr<state>> temp;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != states.size(); ++i)
    {
        if ( /* move? */)
        {
            temp.push_back(std::move(states[i]));
        }
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != temp.size(); ++i)
    {
        // process temp[i]
    }
}
```

The removed elements will be null pointers in the `states` vector at the end of each loop body, so you may wish to prune those:

```
states.erase(std::remove(states.begin(), states.end(), nullptr), states.end());
```

(At the moment there aren't any `std::copy_if` and `std::move_if` algorithms, but once they're added to the standard library, this code will become a lot shorter.)

Comment: Transfer the elements I wish to delete? Those elements your transferring I don't want deleted, I wan't those elements preserved so that next iteration I can't draw and update them again so I'm sure I follow you. If you mean make this your game loop then this does not work because like you said the elements will be null on the second iteration so there is nothing to be transferd from `states`. This concept doesn't make since to me because I need to _duplicate_ the elements inside `states`somewhere else (in a temp vector).

Comment: @MrPlosion1243: Maybe a `shared_ptr` is more useful in that case? Or just do a `temp.swap(states);` at the end of the loop?